# Add ActionCell to GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I'm trying to add an actioncell to a GWT datagrid and I'm having trouble doing so. I looked in the GWT showcase and found an example that adds an actioncell to a celltable, shown here

```
// ActionCell.
    addColumn(new ActionCell<ContactInfo>(
        "Click Me", new ActionCell.Delegate<ContactInfo>() {
          public void execute(ContactInfo contact) {
            Window.alert("You clicked " + contact.getFullName());
          }
        }), "Action", new GetValue<ContactInfo>() {
      public ContactInfo getValue(ContactInfo contact) {
        return contact;
      }
    }, null);
```

and here is my attempt, but I have no idea on how this is syntaxically supposed to look, how does it work?

```
Column<OpInventory, ActionCell<OpInventory>> checkColumn = new Column<OpInventory,
//I get an error on instantiating the Delegate
ActionCell<OpInventory>>(new ActionCell("x", new ActionCell.Delegate<OpInventory>())) {
            //this is wrong here
        @Override
        public ActionCell getValue(OpInventory object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        };
    table.addColumn(checkColumn, SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<br/>"));
    table.setColumnWidth(checkColumn, 40, Unit.PX);
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out the syntax, posting here for others.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        Column<OpInventory, ActionCell> actionCellColumn = new Column<OpInventory, ActionCell>(new ActionCell("See Lots", new ActionCell.Delegate<OpInventory>() {

            @Override
            public void execute(OpInventory object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })){

            @Override
            public ActionCell getValue(OpInventory object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        };
        table.addColumn(actionCellColumn, "See Lot Numbers");
        table.setColumnWidth(actionCellColumn, 40, Unit.PX);
```